# How do I change where Pycharm is trying to find my main.py file?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pythoninterpreter

[Main.py causes error when in a folder but not when in test folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kKe2.jpg)

Every time I run a .py file in Pycharm when it is in a folder this error happens. I speculate that it has something to do with the interpreter or the virtual environment but I am not sure. The interpreter does not allow me to find or employ other interpreters either. Information for this and the code I was using is in the photo, I am new to programming and have yet to find anyone else with this problem (unless it's a feature).

Answer (score 0):

Change the folder name from `pomodoro-start` to `pomodoro_start`; symbols like (@#$%^&*-) will cause the Python interpreter to not recognize it as a valid folder on the path.

From your picture:
 `'/Users/andrewwong/PycharmProjects/test/main.py'` 
should be:
`'/Users/andrewwong/PycharmProjects/test/pomodoro_start/main.py'`
Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for the input! It did not work but I think it was because the virtual environment configures main.py to the main folder and doesnt change after I put it inside. Fixed now!